# How to create a new azure storage account in the new "Cool" tier

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage

Azure just released the new "Azure Storage Cool tier" (cheaper per GB, but more expensive read/write and only 99% availability SLA).

It's easy to create an account using the azure portal, but does anybody know how to create a "cool tier" storage account using Powershell?

Comment: "Cool" tier = Azure-Resource Manager ?

Comment: "Cool" tier = Azure-Resource Manager => Not really! Azure Resource Manager is much more than that. To answer the question, I don't think PS Cmdlets have been updated to support "Cool" tier just yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the release with Cool tier support at:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/tag/v1.4.0-May2016

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/download/v1.4.0-May2016/azure-powershell.1.4.0.msi

Answer (score 3):

i believe there are no Powershell commandlets yet to do that. I took a look at the [REST API of the Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163564.aspx), and there is the possibility to create the storage account with the access type. As Powershell somehow use the API, it seems that documentation was not updated yet or that functionality was not exposed yet via Powershell. I would wait for the next Azure PS update/release.

Comment: Alex, you're looking in the wrong place. The correct link for Storage Resource Provider REST API to create a storage account is this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163564.aspx. HTH.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav! Change my answer.